# Get all injected script files

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I know I can get all `<script>` from DOM with jquery:
`$('script[type="text/javascript"]')`

But how can I get all injected scripts? for example by dojo.
I can see them in developer tools

[image]

`$('script[type="text/javascript"]').length === 0`

Comment: $('script') should work for even injected scripts.

Comment: Please note that `$('script[type="text/javascript"]')` only returns those script elements that _explicitly_ have that exact type attribute, and it won't return elements starting with `<script>` or `<script type="application/javascript">`, even though those are JavaScript by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah sorry guys.
There is an iframe and the scrips are just inside. So if i ask for $('script') inside it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
document.scripts.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the scripts when the  document is ready

```
$(function(){
console.log($('script[type="text/javascript"]').length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `cache` and `modules` properties of `require`:

```
console.log(require.cache);
console.log(require.modules);
```